# Rewriting domain part in a reverse proxy - mod_proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I have a couple of internal websites that I want to make them available to the Internet with new domain names. I'm thinking of a reverse proxy frontend and I need it to direct all requests like so:

```
([^\.]*)\.company\.com --> $1.internal
```

I know this is done using mod_rewrite and mod_proxy but I'm not sure how! The key point is that I don't want to name all the DSNs one by one as their list is dynamic and might change over time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question, it's called **[mod_proxy_express](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_express.html)** and it's available in Apache 2.4.